# An issue with admin.autodiscover()

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am having a problem with `admin.autodiscover()`. I just moved my site from the system I was building it on to the server it will stay on for production use. The system that was being used to build it is Windows 7 however the production server is Debian Squeeze 64bit.

The problem is that I am getting the error `The model UserProfile is already registered`. I am not having this problem with the Windows 7 computer, only once it moves to Debian it does.

admin.py

```
class UserProfileadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'country', 'totalflights', 'totalhours', 'hub']
    search_fields = ['user']
    list_filter = ['hub']
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
         if db_field.name == 'hub':
             kwargs['queryset'] = Airports.objects.filter(hub=True)

    return super(UserProfileadmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(UserProfile,UserProfileadmin)
class PilotRankadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['ranktitle', 'minimumhours', 'pay']
    search_fields = ['ranktitle']

admin.site.register(PilotRank, PilotRankadmin)

class PIREPadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'flightnumber']
    search_fields = ['ranktitle']

admin.site.register(PIREP, PIREPadmin)
```

Any ideas? I have never had this before when working on a Windows system then moving to a Linux system for production.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ma84r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the error stack details...
have you tried using admin.site.unregister(UserProfile) just before you call register ?

edit:
this seems to be working fine for me -

```
if not admin.site._registry.has_key(UserProfile):
        admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

Comment: Yes, here it is with the line you suggested above.

http://prntscr.com/ma7y6

Here is the stack without it

http://prntscr.com/ma84r

Comment: It usually occurs if you are importing models from multiple places
see if this works try..except block
`try:
 admin.site.register(UserProfile)
except AlreadyRegistered:
 pass`

Comment: Thank you for the help it is now working :) I am wondering though, why would a linux system need this however on windows it would not

Comment: good that it worked for you... can't say for sure why it's throwing that error to you, probably you need to review your code and all imports again
btw, got this another solution for your problem and it seems to be working fine for me -
`if not admin.site._registry.has_key(UserProfile):
    admin.site.register(UserProfile)`